# Can most old index theorems be rewritten in the language of k theory?

Tags: index-theory

So I am very new to index theorems and K theory. I know K theory is the modern language of index theory these days. I was just wondering if we take some papers on some index theorems that do not use any K theory.

Say the following:

1. https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2010-362-08/S0002-9947-10-05170-6/S0002-9947-10-05170-6.pdf
2. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123672900079

3)https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01350663

Is it always possible to rewrite/ rephrase the theorem in K theoretic language?

And furthermore, what is the reason why one would want to do this?